# Instagram crossdomain.xml for profile pictures

Tags: instagram, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to access Instagram through a flash web app. I can access the Instagram API the the users' photos because there's a corssdomain.xml file api.instagram.com and distilleryimage.s3.amazonaws.com
But the profile pictures are stored at: http://images.ak.instagram.com and there doesn't seem to be a crossdomain.xml file there so I can't access it.

Is there a way to access it?
Can someone in Instagram please add a crossdomain.xml to the profile pictures domain?

Thanks!

Comment: You're loading an *image* from that domain, not loading it in an iFrame or making an ajax request. Mine, for instance, is here: http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_909450_75sq_1388362499.jpg and you can load it all sorts of ways and even embed it in html <img> tags.

Comment: Hi remus. I'm trying to load the image in a Flash app using a URLLoader just as I do with the actual photos stored on amazonaws. So far I couldn't find a way to load the image in Flash in a way that doesn't require the crossdomain.xml file to be present. Also, amazonaws also stores images and there is a crossdomain.xml file there so I can't understand why there shouldn't be one where the profile pictures are stored.

Comment: Hrm, that is really bizarre. Either way, if you need something like that you'll need to contact Instagram support directly; SO can't help with that kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah.. they said they're following StackOverflow so I'm hoping they'll see this.

Comment: They might be saying that, but they're not - there hasn't been a single authoritative answer on SO from anyone at IG. Moreover, SO isn't a free-for-all support forum for vendors like IG.

Comment: That's what it says on their developer support page.. Anyway, I tried to submit an issue in their bug tool, lets see if it helps.

Comment: Sadly it does - however I'm 99% sure they didn't consult with SO before posting that, and no one here from IG ever answers questions tagged <instagram>